# ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename doesn't save and no error code (that I see)

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, save-as

I'm a newbie.  I have code that I inherited that copies worksheets from a monthly workbook into a new workbook and creates a summary sheet.  It works for April data, but for May and later months' data when it gets to the save it spins a bit and then just dies with no error code.  I can't figure out what must be different between the monthly worksheets that could be making this die. I've run in immediate mode and I'm still not seeing any indication of the problem. Any suggestion on how to track down the problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
wb2.Activate
Sheets("977-053").Select 'Add sheets
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 4")).Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("RH ARAP Summary BASIC.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Chavez").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
wb2.Activate
Sheets("977-05J").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("RH ARAP Summary BASIC.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Pangburn").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
wb2.Activate
Sheets("977-05K").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("RH ARAP Summary BASIC.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Geier").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
wb2.Activate
Sheets("977-05R").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("RH ARAP Summary BASIC.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Martin").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close opened TO 5
MsgBox "ready to Save"
Sheets("RH ARAP Summary").Select 'save ARAP to division folder to send


ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="May-2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code was largely generated by the macro recorder. What it's doing is quite simple, but it is difficult to  work with in this form. If you change it so that variables are defined, it will be much cleaner and easier to work with.

To get you started, here is a simple bit of code that does something similar, with variables properly defined. The animated .gif shows it working to copy the contents from a sheet in one workbook to a sheet in another (click for detail). Hopefully after studying it you can adjust to solve your problem.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r2 As Range
Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
Set sh2 = wb2.Worksheets("977-053")
Set r2 = sh2.Range("A1")
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name = "Book2" Then
        Set sh = wb.Worksheets("Chavez")
        sh.Cells.Copy
        sh2.Activate
        r2.Select
        sh2.Paste
    End If
Next
End Sub
```